# Presenting both iAds and AdMobAds on the iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, iad, admob

I'm currently using the AdWhirl SDK for the iPhone so I can switch Ad Networks depending on Ad-Availability.

Now there is no AdWhirl SDK for the iPad, so I just show AdMob ads.

But in iOS 4.2 we can now show iAds on the iPad too, and it would be nice to combine the two.

Is there a tutorial on how to exactly combine them?

I mean I did some manual switching between the too, in the usual delegate methods that get called when one of the two fails to load etc.

But it's really hard to test if this is working properly and stable, since on the actual Devices the fillrates for iAd will be ~10% and AdMob ~60%.
Now testing this the iAd-Test Advertisement shows up all the time, so I can't really test whether AdMob would show up, would iAd refuse to present an Ad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I wrote an iAd/AdMob wrapper that's available on [github](https://github.com/larsacus/LARSAdController). As little as one line of code will get both ads running and it's currently what I use with my app that's on the app store. It supports both iPhone and iPad in all orientations if you properly implement the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to roll your own, [Mobclix](http://mobclix.com/developer) offers something similar to AdWhirl for iPads

Comment: Sure, Mobclix works for the iPad, only thing is it doesn't support iAds for iPad. For iPhone, yes, but not for iPad.